# Error: The 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, ado.net, oledb

I have developed one 32 bit web application which is using Access database (Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0).
Now I have converted it into 64 bit. 
For this I have changed Target CPU property to x64.
I was getting Error as

```
 The 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
```

then I installed Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0.
But now it is giving error as

```
The 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
```

Please help me..

Comment: Verify your installation of the engine. Check if this file exists. "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\ACEOLEDB.DLL"

Answer (score 0):

There are two versions of Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0, for 32bit and 64bit. You have to install the 64bit version of it, since your application is of 64bit.

"AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe"

Try changing the configuration to x86.

Comment: I am getting this error when I browse through IIS. And Office version is 2007

Comment: Yes.. C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\ACEOLEDB.DLL exists..